# Constant Pointer / structs

Tags: pointers, struct, constants

In my programming class, we have

```
struct Time {
    int hours, min, sec;
}
```

We are to create a method to compute the difference between two times:

`Time *timeDiff(const Time *t1, const Time *t2)`

I thought I could create the time difference by getting everything in seconds, and then subtracting the two values, but it seems like extra work to do something like

```
long hour1 = t1->hours;
long min1 = t1->min;
long sec1 = t1->sec;
```

And then using these values to get the time in seconds, do something similar for the second time, and then subtract.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: The way you described is actually a very reasonable way to do it.  Computers are stupid like that.

I'm assuming that both time values will always be within the same day, without any concern that two time values might span more than one day.

Is it possible for t1 to be earlier in the day than t2 and vice versa?  Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

The way you've described it sounds exactly right. I might do something like

```
int sec = t1->sec + 60*(t1->min + 60*t1->hours);
```

Then similarly for t2, then subtract one from the other and break the result down into minutes and hours.

Comment: Agreed that this is the most general way - and easily expandable to include days. Create two functions - one to convert struct Time to secs and one to do the reverse.